# map_dbl returns a numeric matrix

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

Here is a sample code I'm stuck in.

I define a function. Input a number `x`, output a vector `vec`

```
fct <- function(x){
  vec = vector("numeric",3)
  vec = c(1, x, x^2)
  return(vec)
}
```

I have a sequence `a = 1:10`, then I wish to apply `fct` on `a`. Ideally, it should return a numeric matrix. I know using `sapply(a,fct)` can achieve the purpose. But I'm curious how about using `map_*`.

I tried `map(a,fct)`. It returns a list.

I tried `map_dbl(a,fct)`. It returned an error

```
Error: Result 1 must be a single double, not a double vector of length 3
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

So how this can be done with `map_*`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`map_*` functions don't do this easily. I suggest using the tool that works best and into a known format/structure.

If you're motivation for using `map_dbl` is type-safety (a strength of the `purrr::map*` functions), then you can achieve the same safety with base R:

```r
vapply(a, fct, numeric(3))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
# [2,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
# [3,]    1    4    9   16   25   36   49   64   81   100
```

Granted, `vapply` requires you to know both the class and the length of the return value a priori, but if that's not a problem, then you're good. Additionally, it's generally pretty fast:

```r
a <- 1:10
bench::mark(vapply(a, fct, numeric(3)), lapply(a, fct), sapply(a, fct), map(a, fct), check = FALSE)
# # A tibble: 4 x 13
#   expression                      min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result memory                 time              gc                   
#   <bch:expr>                 <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list> <list>                 <list>            <list>               
# 1 vapply(a, fct, numeric(3))   12.3us   18.1us    44793.      288B     0    10000     0      223ms <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [1 x 3]> <bch:tm [10,000]> <tibble [10,000 x 3]>
# 2 lapply(a, fct)               11.6us   16.2us    52398.        0B     5.24  9999     1      191ms <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [0 x 3]> <bch:tm [10,000]> <tibble [10,000 x 3]>
# 3 sapply(a, fct)               24.8us     36us    22943.      576B     2.29  9999     1      436ms <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [2 x 3]> <bch:tm [10,000]> <tibble [10,000 x 3]>
# 4 map(a, fct)                  24.2us   32.4us    24356.        0B     2.44  9999     1      411ms <NULL> <Rprofmem[,3] [0 x 3]> <bch:tm [10,000]> <tibble [10,000 x 3]>
```

(Note that the performance differences almost go away as the length of `a` increases.)

But going back to `map*`, you *can* use `purrr` with only a small outer function,

```r
invoke(cbind, map(a, fct))
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
# [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
# [2,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
# [3,]    1    4    9   16   25   36   49   64   81   100
```

And its performance, though slower, is not a lot slower, and with larger data the differences are reduced.

```r
a <- 1:10
bench::mark(vapply(a, fct, numeric(3)), sapply(a, fct), do.call(cbind, lapply(a, fct)), do.call(cbind, map(a, fct)), invoke(cbind, map(a, fct)), matrix(flatten_dbl(map(a, fct)), ncol = length(a)))
# # A tibble: 6 x 13
#   expression                                              min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result             memory              time            gc                
#   <bch:expr>                                         <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>             <list>              <list>          <list>            
# 1 vapply(a, fct, numeric(3))                           12.3us     17us    51210.      288B     5.12  9999     1      195ms <dbl[,10] [3 x 10~ <Rprofmem[,3] [1 x~ <bch:tm [10,00~ <tibble [10,000 x~
# 2 sapply(a, fct)                                       25.2us   36.4us    22276.      576B     2.23  9999     1      449ms <dbl[,10] [3 x 10~ <Rprofmem[,3] [2 x~ <bch:tm [10,00~ <tibble [10,000 x~
# 3 do.call(cbind, lapply(a, fct))                       16.2us   22.7us    37430.      288B     3.74  9999     1      267ms <dbl[,10] [3 x 10~ <Rprofmem[,3] [1 x~ <bch:tm [10,00~ <tibble [10,000 x~
# 4 do.call(cbind, map(a, fct))                          31.8us   43.6us    19856.      288B     4.40  9026     2      455ms <dbl[,10] [3 x 10~ <Rprofmem[,3] [1 x~ <bch:tm [9,028~ <tibble [9,028 x ~
# 5 invoke(cbind, map(a, fct))                           35.8us   49.6us    17440.      288B     2.07  8408     1      482ms <dbl[,10] [3 x 10~ <Rprofmem[,3] [1 x~ <bch:tm [8,409~ <tibble [8,409 x ~
# 6 matrix(flatten_dbl(map(a, fct)), ncol = length(a))   29.6us   45.2us    19309.      864B     2.08  9292     1      481ms <dbl[,10] [3 x 10~ <Rprofmem[,3] [3 x~ <bch:tm [9,293~ <tibble [9,293 x ~

a <- 1:1000
bench::mark(vapply(a, fct, numeric(3)), sapply(a, fct), do.call(cbind, lapply(a, fct)), do.call(cbind, map(a, fct)), invoke(cbind, map(a, fct)), matrix(flatten_dbl(map(a, fct)), ncol = length(a)))
# # A tibble: 6 x 13
#   expression                                              min   median `itr/sec` mem_alloc `gc/sec` n_itr  n_gc total_time result                 memory               time         gc              
#   <bch:expr>                                         <bch:tm> <bch:tm>     <dbl> <bch:byt>    <dbl> <int> <dbl>   <bch:tm> <list>                 <list>               <list>       <list>          
# 1 vapply(a, fct, numeric(3))                           1.05ms   1.35ms      714.    23.5KB     4.33   330     2    461.9ms <dbl[,1000] [3 x 1,00~ <Rprofmem[,3] [1 x ~ <bch:tm [33~ <tibble [332 x ~
# 2 sapply(a, fct)                                       1.13ms   1.41ms      655.    70.8KB     4.31   304     2      464ms <dbl[,1000] [3 x 1,00~ <Rprofmem[,3] [6 x ~ <bch:tm [30~ <tibble [306 x ~
# 3 do.call(cbind, lapply(a, fct))                        1.4ms    1.7ms      543.    31.3KB     4.33   251     2    462.1ms <dbl[,1000] [3 x 1,00~ <Rprofmem[,3] [2 x ~ <bch:tm [25~ <tibble [253 x ~
# 4 do.call(cbind, map(a, fct))                          1.66ms   1.78ms      479.    31.3KB    10.2     47     1     98.1ms <dbl[,1000] [3 x 1,00~ <Rprofmem[,3] [2 x ~ <bch:tm [48~ <tibble [48 x 3~
# 5 invoke(cbind, map(a, fct))                            1.3ms   1.73ms      546.    39.2KB     4.30   254     2    464.8ms <dbl[,1000] [3 x 1,00~ <Rprofmem[,3] [3 x ~ <bch:tm [25~ <tibble [256 x ~
# 6 matrix(flatten_dbl(map(a, fct)), ncol = length(a))   1.13ms   1.49ms      551.    78.3KB     2.07   266     1    482.8ms <dbl[,1000] [3 x 1,00~ <Rprofmem[,3] [4 x ~ <bch:tm [26~ <tibble [267 x ~
```

(The output of the six commands are identical.)

Comment: OK! I will look into ```vapply```.

Comment: I also figured out that ```map_dfc``` may also work out.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why `sapply` returns a matrix is because it has an argument `simplify` which is `TRUE` by default. The `simplify` argument tries to simplifies the result to vector/matrix. If you change the argument to `FALSE` you'll get the same output as `lapply` or `map`.

```
sapply(a,fct, simplify = FALSE) 

#[[1]]
#[1] 1 1 1

#[[2]]
#[1] 1 2 4

#[[3]]
#[1] 1 3 9

#[[4]]
#[1]  1  4 16
#...
#...
```

`map` will always return a list whereas `map_dbl` expects a single number to be returned from the function, in your case the function returns 3 numbers. So an option is to construct a matrix from the output of `map`.

```
library(purrr)

map(a, fct) %>% 
  flatten_dbl() %>% 
  matrix(ncol = length(a))

#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
#[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
#[2,]    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9    10
#[3,]    1    4    9   16   25   36   49   64   81   100
```

Answer (score 0):

`a %>% map(fct) %>% reduce(cbind)` returns a matrix.